# Avoid double registration through facebook Registration plugin

Tags: facebook, registration

I am using facebook registration plugin for my website. But it allows registration for users who are already registered with my website. Can I prevent this using Registration plugin?

Comment: Registration plugin is just a plugin which helps us to authenticate user through facebook and to get them registered into our website/application. As a developer you have make sure whether that user already registered into your site and then display the registration plugin or let him login into your site.

Comment: Yeah I am doing that check.. but just thought if there is some functionality from facebook side.. btw thanks

Comment: Thats fine. There is no other functionality in FB that can check whether this user is registered into your site and FB don't have any control over your website? Is there anything else you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a functionality. It would be to difficult to implement.
For example, it would be necessary for you to give the facebook plugin access to your user database, a db that can vary from site to site, so it can compare the users you have with the one who wants to register.

In short, no.